# android google map overlays ontap

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, touch, overlay

I have created 3 classes. Each of them extends Overlay. And each of them has "complex" overrided draw method. And that is why I choose to override Overlay instead of use ItemizedOverlay. Now for determining which overlay has been tapped it would be easier to ha ItemizedOverlay but still I'm using "normal" Overlay. How to proper determine which of my overlays has been tapped.

I have overrided onTap method in every (of three) classes that extends Overlay. And result is that no matter where on map I touch all three classes' onTap is called.

Do I have to calculate based on onTap's method argument GeoPoint and my current location if I touched my drawing or not? How to do it properly? Change everything to ItemizedOverlay? If so, how to do complex drawings of some overlays?

10x
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created solution:

```
@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint geoPoint, MapView mapView) {
    // Gets mapView projection to use it with calculations
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    Point tapPoint = new Point();
    // Projects touched point on map to point on screen relative to top left corner
    projection.toPixels(geoPoint, tapPoint);

    // Gets my current GeoPoint location
    GeoPoint myLocationGeoPoint = getLocationGeoPoint();

    // Image on the screen width and height
    int pinWidth = myPin.getWidth();
    int pinHeight = myPin.getHeight();

    // Variable that handles whether we have touched on image or not
    boolean touched = false;

    if (myLocationGeoPoint != null) {
        Point myPoint = new Point();

        // Projects my current point on map to point on screen relative to top left corner
        projection.toPixels(myLocationGeoPoint , myPoint);

        // Because image bottom line is align with GeoPoint and this GeoPoint is in the middle of image we have to do some calculations
        // absDelatX should be smaller that half of image width because as I already said image is horizontally center aligned
        int absDeltaX = Math.abs(myPoint.x - tapPoint.x);
        if (absDeltaX < (pinWidth / 2)) {
            // Because image is vertically bottom aligned with GeoPoint we have to be sure that we hace touched above GeoPoint (watch out: points are top-left corner based)
            int deltaY = myPoint.y - tapPoint.y;
            if (deltaY < pinHeight) {
                // And if we have touched above GeoPoint and belov image height we have win!
                touched = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (touched) {
        Log.d(TAG, "We have been touched! Yeah!");
    }

    return true;
}
```